# Syntax error when using Delimiters with Aurora Serverless MySQL 5.6

Tags: mysql, aws-aurora-serverless

I'm using Aurora Serverless MySQL 5.6 to create the following trigger which will update one table when data is inserted into another table but am receiving syntax errors, specifically around the Delimiter keyword.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER Create_Media_Like_Trigger AFTER INSERT ON MediaLike
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
    IF NEW.likeType = 'LIKE' THEN
        UPDATE Media 
        SET Media.numLikes = Media.numLikes + 1 
        WHERE Media.mediaId = NEW.mediaId;
    ELSEIF NEW.likeType = 'DISLIKE' THEN
        UPDATE Media 
        SET Media.numLikes = Media.numLikes - 1 
        WHERE Media.mediaId = NEW.mediaId;
    ENDIF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Like I said above, I am receiving syntax errors near `DELIMITER`, is this issue AWS specific and how can I fix it?

UPDATE with error messages:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server 
version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER $$ CREATE TRIGGER Create_Media_Like_Trigger 
AFTER INSERT ON MediaLike ' at line 1

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server 
version for the right syntax to use near 'ELSEIF NEW.likeType = 'DISLIKE' THEN UPDATE Media SET 
Media.numLikes = Media.num' at line 1

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server 
version for the right syntax to use near 'END $$' at line 1
```

Comment: It might be helpful if you add the actual error message. Also, how you run this code. (The delimiter is specific to the client, not the server.)

Comment: @Solarflare I'm running it on the RDS console, and just updated the post with the error messages

Answer (score 3):

I spent a day trying to figure this out so hopefully this helps someone out there...

`DELIMITER` is a feature of the client, not the MySQL server. The RDS Query Editor is a client but it does not support changing the delimiter so attempting to run the script you've provided won't work since the first time it sees a semicolon it will interpret that as the end of the command and fail with a syntax error.

So, how do you create something like a stored procedure that has multiple statements and semicolons in it? You must create it as an `.sql` file and send it using the Data API from either a Lambda function or the CLI.

First, create your script in a `.sql` file without any `DELIMITER` commands or alternate delimiters.

For example: `function.sql`

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE simpleproc (OUT param1 INT)
BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT(*) INTO param1 FROM t;
END
```

Then, run the script using the CLI like this:

```sh
cat function.sql | xargs -0 aws rds-data execute-statement \
    --resource-arn arn:aws:rds:eu-west-1:xxx:cluster:cluster-name \
    --secret-arn arn:aws:secretsmanager:eu-west-1:xxx:secret:secret-name-xxx \
    --database "database_name" \
    --sql
```

Alternatively, you can create a Lambda function that reads the file and uses `rds_client.execute_statement()` to send the script to the server via the Data API. But again, do NOT use the `DELIMITER` statement. The server sees the `BEGIN` and `END` lines and acts accordingly without the need to change the delimiter.

Comment: +1 I've been hunting how to upload Stored Procs to the Aurora Serverless DB for quite a while now.  Thanks!

Comment: what is the windows version of pointing to a file before calling the aws rds-data command?  cat is not a command for windows

Answer (score 0):

This info may not strictly be relevant to the OP's question, but it's closely related and may help someone else in a similar situation (ie. from a search).

I was running a similar `CREATE FUNCTION` query on an Amazon Aurora Serverless MySQL 5.6 database, and was getting the same syntax errors. I was using Table Plus (v2.9.1, build 264) as my application/client.

The solution was to delete the 2x `DELIMITER` lines. The application/client was intelligent enough to work out the delimiters itself.

Answer (score 0):

After quite a while of messing with the DELIMITER keyword, I found the following works.

```html
DROP FUNCTION sf_CheckUser;
DELIMITER / / 
CREATE FUNCTION db1.sf_CheckUser (
    userUUID VARCHAR(255),
    groupUUID VARCHAR(255),
    requiredTHING INT
) RETURNS TINYINT(1) 
BEGIN
DECLARE permit TINYINT(1);
        
  -- BODY OF FUNCTION

END / / DELIMITER;
```