# How to add a Stored Procedure to AWS RDS Aurora-Serverless?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, stored-procedures, aws-aurora-serverless

I have an Aurora Serverless MySql database that I would like to add stored procedures to.  I tried the console query editor but that does not work.
The message I receive is:
`You haven't finished running any queries yet.`

I have hunted through a LOT of AWS docs but can not find how to do it.

Could someone please point me in the correct direction?

Andrew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer in an other question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60309133/222837

I was hoping for an article or something from AWS but this gets the job done.  You need to use the CLI and push up a file with the Stored Procedure in it.

```
cat function.sql | xargs -0 aws rds-data execute-statement \
    --resource-arn arn:aws:rds:eu-west-1:xxx:cluster:cluster-name \
    --secret-arn arn:aws:secretsmanager:eu-west-1:xxx:secret:secret-name-xxx \
    --database "database_name" \
    --sql
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the CLoud9 environment in AWS, this way you can access the DB from environment's CLI, just like a regular SQL server.

Comment: Can you provide an example?  I just setup Could9 but I still have all my stored procedures on my computer.  How can I load them into Cloud9/RDS?

Comment: To add a proc using cloud9 I used the following from the environment command-line:
mysql --user=admin --password -h acpp.cluster-xxxxxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com db_name < file-containing-proc.sql

Comment: with the solution above you do need to have the DELIMETER at the top and bottom of the file.  Using aws cli you don't