# Create a stored procedure in Aurora serverless postgres using aws cli in windows 10

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I am trying to create stored procedure in Aurora serverless postgres db.
I tried using the below command from windows cmd:

aws rds-data execute-statement --resource-arn "arn:aws:rds:eu-west-1:xxxx:cluster:democluster"  --database "demo"   --secret-arn "arn:aws:secretsmanager:eu-west-1:xxxx:secret:rds-db-credentials/cluster-U5TWNYQ2UGIBDE64D3ENAxxxx/postgres-xxxx" --sql && type storedProc.sql

Below is the stroredProc.sql:
CREATE PROCEDURE simpleproc (OUT param1 INT)
BEGIN
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO param1 FROM myrecords;
END

Error:
aws.cmd: error: argument --sql-statements: expected one argument
Some time I get issue saying procedure keyword does not exist.

I found this url in stackoverflow but its for Linux.
[How to add a Stored Procedure to AWS RDS Aurora-Serverless?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63399720/how-to-add-a-stored-procedure-to-aws-rds-aurora-serverless)

But any help for windows based aws cli solution will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I realized from the documentation of Postgres, that stored proc is not supported in Postgres v10. Better to use functions than stored procedure.