# Can I create custom stored procedure in AWS Aurora and call AWS Aurora native function lambda_async to invoke AWS Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I want to create a new stored procedure in AWS Aurora MySQL( >3.0.4 or MySQL 8.0) and call the AWS Aurora native function lambda_async to invoke AWS Lambda.

Is it possible to create my own custom stored procedure in AWS Aurora MySQL? How do I create a new stored procedure in AWS Aurora MySQL?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this help in any way? https://stackoverflow.com/q/63399720/4800344